# How to write SQL statement containing 2 conditions in android

Tags: android

I am trying to delete a row from my table if 2 columns equal to what the user entered.

E.g. I have 2 textfields in which the user entered something in both e.g. "chicken" and in the other textfield "car". I want to delete the row in which those 2 values are in a row. I think it will be something like: `delete from ~tablename~ where food = chicken AND vehicle = car`.

Im not sure how to write that in sqlite in android.
I have my SQLitedatabase object and have called the delete method on it, but not sure what to put in the parameters

EDIT = I've managed to do it. Thanks for the below answers but this is how I've done it:
`sqlitedb.delete("Random", "food =? AND vehicle=? ", new String[]{tv.getText.toString(),tv1.getText.toString()});`

tv and tv1 are textfields in my case. Random is my table's name.

Comment: It is considered a good practice to either accept an answer or compose an answer by yourself and accept it, rather than editing the answer inside your question. Since I've noticed that you have a low acceptance rate I'd advice you to also check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!

Answer (score 0):

The sql query will look like -

```
String sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE food = '"+ <food_name> + "' AND vehicle = '" + <vehicle_name> + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
String table_name=~tablename~;
String table_column_one=food;
String table_column_two=vehicle;

database.delete(table_name, 
table_column_one + " = ? AND " + table_column_two + " = ?", 
new String[] {"chicken", "car"});
```

Check [SQLiteDatabase's documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) on delete function for more info.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite accepts conditionals in the WHERE clause as regular SQL.